# What trivial attacks is ASP.NET MVC mixed-mode auth vulnerable to?

Tags: authentication, iis, asp.net-mvc

In a 2012 MSDN blog post, Microsoft discourages mixed-mode authentication in
ASP.NET MVC for being vulnerable to trivial attacks:

> The ASP.NET team doesn’t support using mixed-mode authentication in an
>   application. If you search the web, you’ll find blog posts on how to do
>   this, but please note that the techniques discussed in these blog posts are
>   discouraged by the team. The reason this is discouraged is that it is very
>   difficult to reason about security from a correctness point of view, and
>   there are trivial attacks against such a setup that can allow malicious
>   clients to masquerade as an authenticated user. If a supported/secure
>   approach to using mixed-mode authentication is important to you, make a
>   request on our UserVoice page.
>   ([source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rickandy/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute/))

For context, this was a couple years before [OWIN-MixedAuth](https://github.com/MohammadYounes/OWIN-MixedAuth)
came about. I don't know if [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9008755/1958726)
from January 2012 is representative of the kind of advice blogs were giving at
the time, but it recommends mixing WebPages with MVC and placing a JavaScript
redirect on IIS's 401 page.

It would be useful to know what attacks Microsoft is referring to in
order to evaluate the security of current solutions like OWIN-MixedAuth.